# Find sub-words in a string using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

In trying to solve [this challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-substring) (which I pasted at the bottom of this question) using Python 3, the first of the two proposed solutions below, passes all test cases, while the second one doesn't. Since, in my eyes, they're doing pretty much the same, this leaves me very confused. Why doesn't the second block of code work?
It must be something very obvious because the second one fails most test cases, but having worked through custom-inputs, I still can't figure it out.

Working solution:

```
import re
import sys

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

n=int(lines[0])
q=int(lines[n+1])

N=lines[1:n+1]
S=lines[n+2:]

text = "\n".join(N)
for s in S:
    print(len(re.findall(r"(?<!\W)(?="+s.strip()+r"\w)", text)))
```

Broken "solution":

```
import re
import sys

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

n=int(lines[0])
q=int(lines[n+1])

N=lines[1:n+1]
S=lines[n+2:]

for s in S:
    total=0
    for string in N:
        total += len(re.findall("(?<!\W)(?="+s.strip()+"\w)", string))
    print(total)
```

---

We define a *word character* to be any of the following:

- An English alphabetic letter (i.e., a-z and A-Z).
- A decimal digit (i.e., 0-9).
- An underscore (i.e., _, which corresponds to ASCII value ).

We define a *word* to be a contiguous sequence of one or more word characters that is preceded and succeeded by one or more occurrences of non-word-characters or line terminators. For example, in the string *I l0ve-cheese_?*, the words are *I*, *l0ve*, and *cheese_*.

We define a *sub-word* as follows:

- A sequence of word characters (i.e., English alphabetic letters,
  digits, and/or underscores) that occur in the same exact order (i.e.,
  as a contiguous sequence) inside another word.
- It is preceded and succeeded by word characters only.

Given sentences consisting of one or more words separated by non-word characters, process queries where each query consists of a single string, . To process each query, count the number of occurrences of as a sub-word in all sentences, then print the number of occurrences on a new line.

**Input Format**

The first line contains an integer, *n*, denoting the number of sentences.
Each of the subsequent lines contains a sentence consisting of words separated by non-word characters.
The next line contains an integer, , denoting the number of queries.
Each line of the subsequent lines contains a string, , to check.

**Constraints**

- *1 ≤ n ≤ 100*
- *1 ≤ q ≤ 10*

**Output Format**

For each query string, print the total number of times it occurs as a sub-word within all words in all sentences.

**Sample Input**

```
1
existing pessimist optimist this is
1
is
```

**Sample Output**

```
3
```

Explanation

We must count the number of times is occurs as a sub-word in our input sentence(s):

- occurs time as a sub-word of existing.
- occurs time as a sub-word of pessimist.
- occurs time as a sub-word of optimist.
- While is a substring of the word this, it's followed by a blank
  space; because a blank space is non-alphabetic, non-numeric, and not
  an underscore, we do not count it as a sub-word occurrence.
- While is a substring of the word is in the sentence, we do not count
  it as a match because it is preceded and succeeded by non-word
  characters (i.e., blank spaces) in the sentence. This means it
  doesn't count as a sub-word occurrence.

Next, we sum the occurrences of as a sub-word of all our words as *1+1+1+0+0=3*. Thus, we print *3* on a new line.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. The problem statement is fine, but how exactly is your code broken? Can you dumb down this problem statement? There's a lot of text here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It is broken in the sense that it doesn't pass all the test cases. For all I know it might not even be broken, but I lack the expertise to judge so, hence my question. I think I can make the question simpler, but not without lacking completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Without specifying your strings as raw strings, the regex metacharacters are actually interpreted as special escaped characters, and the pattern will not match as you expect.
2. Since you are no longer looking inside a multiline string, you'll want to add modify your negative lookbehind to a positive one: `(?<=\w)`
3. As Wiktor mentions in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659498/find-a-sub-word-hacker-rank-challenge/45659619#comment78286928_45659619), it would be a good idea to escape `s.strip` so that any potential chars that could be treated as regex metachars will be escaped and taken literally. You can use `re.escape(s.strip())` for that.

---

Your code will work with this change:

```
total += len(re.findall(r"(?<\w)(?=" + re.escape(s.strip()) + r"\w)", string))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Alas, I still can't get it to work.It fails the same test cases even specifying "rawness".

Comment: @GitGud Fixed. An additional lookbehind was required.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me figure out what's going on before up voting.

Comment: The additional lookbehind: is it simply ensuring that it is not the beginning of the string?

Comment: @GitGud Yep, that's all it is.

Comment: `(?<!\W)(?<!^)` can be replaced with a single positive lookbehind - `(?<=\w)`. I think that `s.strip()` should be escaped, `re.escape(s.strip())`, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. It's definitely a lot better.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ultimately settled for `findall(r"(?<=\w)(?=%s\w)" %re.escape(s.strip()), string)`. Thank you both.